# Gmail user set up through Google Apps can’t change their password

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm using Gmail to handle my domain's email by creating a MX record for the domain and setting up Google apps. So I'm using my domain name for the email address but Gmail’s interface.

Everything is working fine except a user I set up can't change their password when logged into Gmail—it seems to have to do this through the Google apps interface. Is there a way I can grant users permission to change their passwords? I’ve only set up one user and in Apps it says they are the super administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All users should be able to change their passwords by default. From with in the GMail site as a logged in user (GMail or Google Apps), click the button with your email address in the top right of the screen and then select **Account**. From there, select **Security** > **Password management - Change password**.

Google's documentation is linked [here](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6567), but it seems a bit outdated for gApps users.

Comment: In gmail it was under settings / accounts / Google Account settings / security /

Answer (score 0):

This resolution does not work.

GMail -> Account -> Security -> Password Management -> Change Password -> Gmail

You immediately loop back to the email application as soon as you click Change Password.

The only way is to do an admin change via the Google Apps control panel; something the end users can't do.

This is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for posting this observation. It's not actually an answer. Read the [faq#questions] to know why.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If you are using your own authentication authority then the end-user cannot reset the Google password; which is a real pain as we then need to do it manually for every user who wants to configure their tablet devices. I have spoken to Google about this and they confirmed that it is not possible.